# How to use correctly importlib in a flask controller?

Tags: python, flask, python-importlib

I am trying to load a module according to some settings. I have found a working solution but I need a confirmation from an advanced python developer that this solution is the best performance wise as the API endpoint which will use it will be under heavy load.

The idea is to change the working of an endpoint based on parameters from the user and other systems configuration. I am loading the correct handler class based on these settings. The goal is to be able to easily create new handlers without having to modify the code calling the handlers.

This is a working example :

./run.py :

```
from flask import Flask, abort 
import importlib 
import handlers  

app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/') 
def api_endpoint():     
    try:         
        endpoint = "simple" # Custom logic to choose the right handler        
        handlerClass = getattr(importlib.import_module('.'+str(endpoint), 'handlers'), 'Handler')         
        handler = handlerClass()     
    except Exception as e:         
        print(e)         
        abort(404)      

    print(handlerClass, handler, handler.value, handler.name())      

    # Handler processing. Not yet implemented

    return "Hello World"  

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

One "simple" handler example. A handler is a module which needs to define an Handler class :

./handlers/simple.py :

```
import os  

class Handler:     
    def __init__(self):         
        self.value = os.urandom(5)      

    def name(self):        
        return "simple"
```

If I understand correctly, the import is done on each query to the endpoint. It means IO in the filesystem with lookup for the modules, ...

Is it the correct/"pythonic" way to implement this strategy ?

Comment: I would cache the imports and also whitelist if possible.

Comment: Python caches imports on its own, see [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) and [`reload()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload).

Comment: @plaes : what do you mean by whitelist ?
I will look deeper in the sys.module documentation.

Comment: Whitelist: list of allowed modules

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers. Yes I did not post this part but the endpoint variable is chosen based on a logic where I prevent "module injection" so there is a whitelist.

Comment: @Kay : I understand that python caches import automatically. However here we are in the context of a new HTTP request when the flask route executes. Won't it reload the module each time ? Moreover this implementation forces each handler to implement a class named Handler. It seems bad practice to have many class with this name.

Comment: The body of a module is only executed once on import. You have to use 'reload()` to re-evaluate a module. So there is no trouble in this regards. In Python modules are just objects and using known names in an interface is just an essential part of OOP. IMO your attempt is strange, but it sure should work.

Comment: I am coming from the PHP world where the context is created on each HTTP request that's why I have a hard time understanding this. I am not against doing it over. How would you have implemented this "extension" mechanism ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question moved to codereview. Thanks all for your help : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96533/extension-pattern-in-a-flask-controller-using-importlib

I am closing this thread.